# Bootstrap 3.3.7, navbar dropdown doesn't closes after 1st time clicking 2nd time on the same navbar dropdown item

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

The problem is that if e.g. I have 3 dropdowns in my navbar and open them in this or any other order:

1st, 2nd, 3rd, 1st. So when opening 1st and then 2nd dropdown, the 1st is closed by default (good), then opening 3rd dropdown - the 2nd is closed (good), after opening 3rd and trying to open 1st, the 1st opens but the 3rd dropdown is left open.

I have tried to remove `open` class name from not closed dropdown with `.dropdown` class, but after 3rd time jQuery stops responding and doesn't call my simple code, e.g.

```js
    $(".solution-dropdown").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('goes here1')

        $(".dropdown.open").removeClass("open");
    });
    
    $(".resources-dropdown").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('goes here2')
        $(".dropdown.open").removeClass("open");
    });
    
    $(".company-dropdown").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('goes here3')
        $(".dropdown.open").removeClass("open");
    });
```

And this is my `HTML` code for navbar with multiple dropdowns:

```html
<button
    class="navbar-toggler"
    type="button"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#navbarResponsive"
    aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown solution-dropdown">
        <a href="/" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle solution-dropdown-toggle" data-target=".solution-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">Solutions
            <span class="solution-icon icon icon-chevron-up"></span>
            <span class="solution-icon icon icon-chevron-down"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu solution-dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#one">One</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#two">Two</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#three">Three</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#none">None</a>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown resources-dropdown">
        <a href="/" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle resources-dropdown-toggle" data-target=".resources-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">Resources
            <span class="resources-icon icon icon-chevron-up"></span>
            <span class="resources-icon icon icon-chevron-down"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu resources-dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#blue">Blue</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#green">Green</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#white" target="_blank">White</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#black">Black</a>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown company-dropdown">
        <a href="/" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle company-dropdown-toggle" data-target=".company-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">Company 
            <span class="company-icon icon icon-chevron-up"></span>
            <span class="company-icon icon icon-chevron-down"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu company-dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#FFF">FFF</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#DDD">DDD</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#GGG">GGG</a>
        </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my `HTML` layout I have the bootstrap and jquery imports like this:

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

- What I'm doing wrong here?
- Why jquery doesn't respond after 3rd time clicking on the dropdown?
- Is there any solution so that all 3 dropdowns would open and close as intended and that this solution would be in bootstrap3.3.7?

Comment: Please share a running snippet of your problem for example with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Because after copying your code (without your own jquery) and add the styles of bootstrap everything works fine.

Comment: I do not know which code block is causing the issue so it's hard to add the code with error (because I thought that this should be enough as I use this specific code for navbar) when I do not know where is the error and I cannot add all the repository to the jsfiddle :)

Comment: So how can we help you if we can't reproduce your problem?

Comment: I understand that, but that's the problem that I do not know what is needed more and as I said, to add more code would mean that I need to recreate a lot of plain HTML, nvm. But ok, if you say that with all my code (including jquery and bootstrap links that I have provided) it works for you, then it means that there is something else and now I do not need to think that it's because maybe of some kind of a bug or incompatibility between jquery and bootstrap.

Comment: It looks not that nice dependet of missing classes in the html, but here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/827aLk91/. If you have more informations about the problem you can update your question or something else.

Comment: Ok, I will add more info when I will find it, but for now thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could not find any other option why by default it doesn't work, but I found bug in my jquery code that should remove `open` class from dropdown, so from this:

```
    $(".solution-dropdown").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('goes here1')

        $(".dropdown.open").removeClass("open");
    });
    
    $(".resources-dropdown").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('goes here2')
        $(".dropdown.open").removeClass("open");
    });
    
    $(".company-dropdown").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('goes here3')
        $(".dropdown.open").removeClass("open");
    });
```

I have changed to

```js
    $(".nav-link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $(".dropdown.open").removeClass("open");
    });
```

That solved problem.